# Is Adam optimizer really RMSprop plus momentum? If yes, why it doesn't have a momentum parameter?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, adam

Here is a [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers) to tensorflow optimizers. And there you can see, that RMSprop takes momentum as argument while Adam does not do this. So I am confuzed. Adam optimization pretends to be a RMSprop optimization with momentum, like this:

*Adam = RMSprop + Momentum*

But why then RMSprop does have the momentum parameter and Adam does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the expression "*Adam is RMSProp with momentum*" is widely used indeed, it is just a very rough shorthand description, and it should not be taken at face value; already in the original [Adam paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf), it was explicitly clarified (p. 6):

> There are a few important differences between RMSProp with momentum and Adam: RMSProp with momentum generates its parameter updates using a momentum on the rescaled gradient, whereas Adam updates are directly estimated using a running average of first and second moment of the gradient.

Sometimes, authors make clear that the subject expression is just a loose description, e.g. in the (highly recommended) [Overview of gradient descent optimization algorithms](https://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#adam) (emphasis added):

> Adam also keeps an exponentially decaying average of past gradients mt, **similar** to momentum.

or in [Stanford CS231n: CNNs for Visual Recognition](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#ada) (again, emphasis added):

> Adam is a recently proposed update that **looks a bit** like RMSProp with momentum.

That said, it's true that some other frameworks actually include a `momentum` parameter for Adam, but this is actually the `beta1` parameter; here is [CNTK](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.learners.html#cntk.learners.adam):

> **momentum** (float, list, output of `momentum_schedule()`) – momentum schedule. Note that this is the beta1 parameter in the Adam paper. For additional information, please refer to the [this CNTK Wiki article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/BrainScript-SGD-Block#converting-learning-rate-and-momentum-parameters-from-other-toolkits).

So, don't take this too literally, and don't loose your sleep over it.